# Enforce a type mapping with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

An _id member is not mapped to type ObjectId anymore, when its type is only derived from bson.ObjectId:

```
import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type CustomId bson.ObjectId

type Foo struct {
    ID1    CustomId `bson:"_id"` // broken
    ID2    bson.ObjectId         // mapped as expected
}


func main() {
    session, _ := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")
    coll := session.DB("mgodemo").C("foocoll")

    doc := Foo{
        CustomId(bson.NewObjectId()),
        bson.NewObjectId(),
    }

    coll.Insert(doc)
}
```

The _id should have been an *ObjectId* in Mongo.
But it turns out that *string* was choosen:

*Mongo Shell:*

```
> db.foocoll.findOne()
{ "_id" : "XvMn]K� �\f:�", "id2" : ObjectId("58764d6e5d4be120fa0c3ab1") }  // id2 is OK ...

> typeof db.foocoll.findOne()._id
string  // OOps. Should be ObjectId !
```

This may be intended, since *bson.ObjectId* itself is derived from *string*. But here, it's bad for us.

Can we tell mgo to map the _id to ObjectId in the Database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Setter](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Setter) and [Getter](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Getter) interfaces to control the representation in mongo:

```
type CustomId bson.ObjectId

func (id *CustomId) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) error {
   var v bson.ObjectId
   err := raw.Unmarshal(&v)
   *id = CustomId(v)
   return err
}
func (id CustomId) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
   return bson.ObjectId(id), nil
}
```

Comment: Nice. Edited to make it compilable.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
type CustomId bson.ObjectId
```

You are creating a new type and the `mgo` package will not see / recognize it as `bson.ObjectId` anymore (the type `bson.ObjectId` is "hardcoded" in the bson package). The new type will have 0 methods.

I would just stick to `bson.ObjectId`. But if you still want a custom ID type, you may use embedding when creating your `CustomId`: embed a value of type `bson.ObjectId`, and use the `inline` bson flag for the `ID1` field:

```
type CustomId struct {
    bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
}

type Foo struct {
    ID1 CustomId      `bson:",inline"`
    ID2 bson.ObjectId 
}
```

Using it:

```
doc := Foo{
    CustomId{bson.NewObjectId()},
    bson.NewObjectId(),
}
```

This has the advantage that `CustomId` will have all the methods `bson.ObjectId` has, and you can add new ones and "override" existing methods.

Another option would be to use an interface type (e.g. `interface{}`) for your `CustomId`, using it would be a lot "simpler":

```
type CustomId interface{}

type Foo struct {
    ID1 CustomId      `bson:"_id"`
    ID2 bson.ObjectId // mapped as expected
}
```

Using it:

```
doc := Foo{
    bson.NewObjectId(),
    bson.NewObjectId(),
}
```

Of course, going down this road, you have to use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), should you need to access the wrapped `bson.ObjectId` of the `CustomId`.

Comment: With the embedding, I see the drawback that Foo must know the CustomId requires to be inlined. Still clever, and works well.