# Anonymous structs return empty field value

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, embedding, mgo

```
type (

    Id struct {
        // I previously forgot to add the `ID` field in my question, it is present in my code but not on this question as @icza pointed it out to me
        ID bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    }

    User struct {
        // When using anonymous struct, upon returning the collection, each of the document will have an empty `id` field, `id: ""`
        Id
        Email string `json:"email" bson:"email"`
        ...
    }

    // This works
    User2 struct {
        ID bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
        Email string `json:"email" bson:"email"`
    }
)
```

I might not have fully understood the concept of anonymous structs yet. In the example above, when querying all users from a collection, the `id` field is going to be an empty string `""`. However, if I directly define the ID field in the `User` struct, the `id` shows up fine. Is this not what anonymous structs are for? Basically extending struct so you won't have to type them again and again?

More example:

```
type SoftDelete struct {
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt time.Time `json:"deleted_at" bson:"deleted_at"`
}

type UserModel struct {
    SoftDelete
}

type BlogPost struct {
    SoftDelete
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that fields having `struct` types (including embedded structs) appear as embedded documents in MongoDB. If you don't want this, you have to specify the `"inline"` bson flag when embedding a struct:

```
User struct {
    Id           `bson:",inline"`
    Email string `json:"email" bson:"email"`
}
```

What the `"inline"` tag does is in MongoDB it "flattens" the fields of the embedded struct as if they were part of the embedder struct.

Similarly:

```
type UserModel struct {
    SoftDelete `bson:",inline"`
}

type BlogPost struct {
    SoftDelete `bson:",inline"`
}
```

<sup>**Edit:** the following section applies to the original `Id` type which embedded `bson.ObjectId`. The asker later clarified that this was just a typo (and edited the question since), and it is a named, non-anonymous field. Still think the info below is useful.</sup>

One thing to note about your `Id` type: Your `Id` type also *embeds* `bson.ObjectId`:

```
Id struct {
    bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
}
```

`Id` not just has a field of `bson.ObjectId`, but it embeds it. This matters because this way you `Id` type will have a `String()` method promoted from `bson.ObjectId`, and so will `User` which embeds `Id`. Having said that, it will be hard trying to print or debug values of type `User`, because you will always see it printed just as a single `ObjectId`.

Instead you can make it a regular field in `Id`, embedding `Id` in `User` will still work as expected:

```
Id struct {
    ID bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
}
```

See related question+asnwer: [Enforce a type mapping with mgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595577/enforce-a-type-mapping-with-mgo/41596169#41596169)

Comment: Ohh sorry, I forgot to type `ID` in the first code block. It's actually there in my code I just forgot to add it to this question. Thanks for pointing out that `inline` tag. That did it for me, thanks heaps! Btw, you have now answered 2 of my `mgo` questions with both as accepted! :)